# Change font size in categories widget title for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the font size for title, i got this code:

```
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Categories' );

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );
```

Any ideas?
Thank You.

Comment: font-size can be manipulated through css and WordPress has a customizer option.

Comment: use css to select the title element and use font-size property to modify font size.

Answer (score 0):

When a theme registers a sidebar it should be something like this:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Name of widgets area',
    'before_widget' => '<div class = "widget-area">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class='widget-title>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  )
);
```

`before_title` and `after_title` specifies the tag (and class) surrounding the title. In your CSS your can use this to add style. For example you can add this to your CSS file:

```
h3.widget-title
{
   font-size: 15px;
}
```